# Safari not showing dragged content

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, drag-and-drop

in my app, I have two tables that support drag & drop between them.

Everything was working fine until I've tested it with Safari (on iMac).

It basically **works on drag and on drop**, the problem is that **it doesn't show the dragged content after "dragstart" is thrown.**

This is extremely annoying because you don't know if you're actually dragging something or not...

**Chrome** (same as Firefox, Opera and Edge):

[image: Dragging on Chrome]

**Safari** (unvisible, but I was dragging in that moment):

[image: Dragging on Safari]

**Now, am I missing something in my code or Safari can't display the dragged content?**

Thanks in advance for your answers!